# PHP http_build_query returns symbols

Tags: php, html, curl

I've been trying to post some data with CURL. The `http_build_query` may be the problem in my case.

I have a long list of information to post, like data mixed with data in arrays.

It looks like, when I do the `http_build_query` it returns an URL full of stange symbols, like this:

```
contact[person]=testes83¶ms[make]=ford¶ms[model]=focus¶ms[version]=mk1-1998-2004
```

Which, in my opinion, causes errors when the server tries to do something with it.

Also I have a word that stars with "re", after http_build_query, it's transformed to ®

```
'region_id' => 1,
```

Transforms into

```
'®gion_id' => 1,
```

Also here's the http_build_query that I'm using

```
 http_build_query($car_info,'', '&');
```

Comment: *The http_build_query may be the problem [...] which, in my opinion, causes errors* You don't sound too convinced yourself, and if you ask me that's the right way to go because I don't think the issue is with `http_build_query` because all that does is basically grab an array and urlencode the keys and values and stick a `=` between them and a `&` between each entry. Nothing in that process should really replace legal URL characters with not legal ones.

Comment: Where/how/when exactly are you seeing that? How are you printing that URL? Is there anything that tries to interpret that URL using some encoding? Since it seems to be the sequence `&re` for instance, is the browser possibly interpreting this as HTML entities…?

Comment: By the way, it's behaving normally for me http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3592758187465f2d3187ac1b7a8acd68c96e8b62

Comment: *"I've been trying to post some data with CURL"* -- post the curl code. [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) works fine but it depends a lot how you use the string it builds.

Comment: *"Transforms into `'®gion_id' => 1,`"* -- are you sure it is not `®ion_id`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bet you put the string returned by [`http_build_quety()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) directly into HTML, without [properly encoding the HTML entities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

As per the HTML standard, there are four characters [(`<`, `>`, `&` and `"`)](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.3.2) that should always be properly encoded using their [entities representation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.3) when they are used in HTML as normal characters:

- `<` must be encoded as `&lt;`;
- `>` as `&gt;`;
- `&` as `&amp;`;
- `"` as `&quot;`.

An HTML character entity always starts with `&` and it should end with `;`. The ending `;` is optional and the browsers can successfully recognize character entities that doesn't end with `;` when they are followed by some characters (white space characters, quotes, dot, comma, `<` etc).

But when the ending `;` is missing, the browser is allowed to try to recognize an incomplete character entity or ignore it and consider `&` represents itself.

The string produced by `html_build_query()` is:

```
contact[person]=testes83&params[make]=ford&region_id=1
```

- it interprets `&para` from `&params` as `¶` (it should be `&para;`);
- it interprets `&reg` from `&region` as `®` (it should be `&reg;`).

**The browser is right!**

Your HTML is invalid and when this happens the browser is allowed to correct it as it pleases!

As @Álvaro González points out in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44757968/php-http-build-query-returns-symbols/44758727#comment76498058_44758727) (thank you!), currently all major browsers recognize character entities when they don't end with `;` and are followed by other letter characters (as it happens in URLs).

You must always use [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or at least [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to properly encode any string you build dynamically before throwing it as text in HTML. **This includes the URLs, even when they are used as values for `href` or `src` HTML attributes.**

Comment: In this case, all major browsers seem to opt for rendering as entity - [online demo](http://jsbin.com/qonohowili/edit?html,output)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález you are right, thank you. I put your comment in the answer, it is helpful. It seems my knowledge about this issue was deprecated. Last time when I wrote a character entity without properly ending it with `;` was more than 15 years ago.

Comment: It's always hard to say whether it's a commonly implemented workaround or something dictated by specs (W3C or WHATWG). If there's a lawyer in the room please edit the answer and add the appropriate quotes, thank you :)

Comment: It seems the browsers interpret `&params=123` as `&para;ms=123` (recognize the character entity) in HTML parts that are meant to be rendered (text) but they don't force a character entity when the string appears in the value of an `href` or `src` attribute; they expect URLs there and this is a common error, that's why they are forgiving in this context.

Comment: Thank you @axiac. I've used the html special chars and there's no those characters.

Comment: just using htmlspecialchars or htmlentities alone isn't enough. __the__ correct way to use htmlentities is `htmlentities ( $str, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED, 'UTF-8', true );` - now, its guaranteed to, as losslessly as possible, convert the input to valid html. but without the proper arguments, its not guaranteed to return valid html.